# Is there a plan to enable preissuance submissions of prior art directly through this site?

Tags: discussion, prior-art

Because preissuance submissions can be submitted for free if it's your first and only submission for a particular application and you're not submitting more than 3 documents, is there any plan to enable those submissions directly from this site? Or maybe somehow enabling those submissions through EFS-Web more easily, directly from here?

Answer (score 8):

We are working with the USPTO to enable submission directly from this site. We don't have official commitment yet, but we've been told by the patent office that it will be free. In general I think that the fee is in place mainly to dissuade "spam", and that if the USPTO thinks that there's high quality submissions coming from Stack Exchange, they will not charge for them.

This is not final, and we will update this answer as the site develops.

Comment: Where can we learn more about this process?  At first I thought the question was a bit of a naive joke.